# Command to track Child process in massif tool

Tags: c++, valgrind, massif

I am using the massif tool in Valgrind. I need to track the heap memory of child process. I couldn't find any command to get the heap memory of child process. My application is a demon server.

In memcheck tool i can able to get the child process details by using

```
--track-children=yes
```

Is there any way to track the child process heap memory using massif ??

The tool creates the log file for all the child process, but it generates the massif file only for the main process.

```
valgrind \
--tool=massif \
--heap=yes \
--time-stamp=yes \
--time-unit=ms \
--max-snapshots=1000 \
--detailed-freq=5 \
--log-file=../Valgrind_%p_massif.log \
--massif-out-file=../masssif_%p_output \
--xtree-memory=full \
<binary_name>
```

I expect the massif file will be generated for all the child process. but it creates only one file foe the main process.

I checked the file last access time. It is the time the main process execution time till waiting for request.

Answer (score 1):

You are missing the option --trace-children=yes

--trace-children is not a memcheck specific option, it is a general valgrind option that must be used with any valgrind tool, if you want the children processes to also run under valgrind after exec.

Comment: Thanks phd. I added the command. Its working. Files generated for the child process. But the massif captures the memory usuage till the deamon server is up and listening to the port. After that none of the memry usuage details were captured.

Comment: Is the daemon server terminating normally ? Also, i suppose this daemon server runs as a normal user (not as root and/ot setuid) ?

Comment: The daemon server will not gets terminated. It runs as a normal user.

Comment: If the daemon server does not terminate, then you have no guarantee about when massif will do some memory dumps.  You can trigger yourself massif output files e.g. using from a shell   "vgdb snapshot".  Do "vgdb help" for the list of allowed actions.

Comment: thanks phd . will try with vgdb..  It also worked when I killed the process using pkill. but its not working all the time.